# Change Text Indent Style with Javascript

Tags: javascript

So in Javascript (not jQuery)

I can set visibility style of a div with an ID of example to visible with the following:

```
document.getElementById("example").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Question is, how do I do the same with the text-indent property? The below doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById("example").style.text-indent = 'none';
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most CSS properties use camel caps:

```
document.getElementById("example").style.textIndent = 'none';
```

Comment: is 'none' a valid value, I think 0 is the default value?

Comment: Great thanks! Won't let me accept the answer this soon, though, so waiting then will.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("example").style.textIndent = 'none';
```

Note the `textIndent`. Variable names in javascript are not allowed to have "-" in the name, so styles like these are converted to camel case when referenced as javascript object properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link answers your question http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_textindent.asp

-> `document.getElementById("example").style.textIndent="50px";`

**-- Edit --** 
I am told that W3School is not a good source of information in some cases. See w3fools.com